Clique number of the line graph of a bipartite graph
Given a bipartite graph $G$ with bipartition $(X,Y)$, let $L(G)$ be the line graph of $G$, i.e., $V(L(G)) = E(G)$ and $e_1e_2 \in E(L(G))$ if and only if they have a common vertex.
The clique number $\omega(G)$ is the maximum number of vertices in $G$ that are pairwise adjacent.
Denote by $\Delta(G)$ the maximum degree of $G$.
It is clear that $\omega(L(G)) \ge \Delta(G)$. Consider a vertex $v$ of maximum degree, the edges incident to $v$ form a clique of size $\Delta(G)$ in $L(G)$.
The question is, does the equality hold?

@Smylic $K_3$ is also not a bipartite graph.

We show $\omega(L(G)) \leq \Delta(G)$. A clique in the line graph $L(G)$ is a set of edges of $G$ that all share an end in $G$. Consider a maximum clique $K$ in $L(G)$, and an edge $uv$ of $G$ in $K$. Now, every other vertex of $K$ corresponds to an edge in $G$ with an end $u$ or $v$. Suppose there exists $au$ and $bv$ vertices in $K$, for $a, b$ distinct from $u, v$. Then $a=b$ since $au$ and $bv$ share an end. But then $\{a, u, v\}$ induced a triangle in $G$, contradicting the bipartiteness of $G$. Thus, all vertices in $K$ share the same common end in $G$, say $v$. Hence $\omega(L(G))\leq \deg(v)\leq \Delta(G)$, as desired.
